# Scaling entire font horizontally

Tags: font-forge

I have a handwriting font (TTF/OpenType) I created with another tool.  I like how it looks, but I would like to have a variant which is equivalent to a 125% horizontal stretch:

I'm aware that this affects vertical line thickness but not horizontal etc. but I'm fine with that:

[image]

[image]

How can I scale my font like this, including all spacing/kerning/glyphs/ligatures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the font, this should show you the entire font.

1. Select all glyphs **Edit → Select → Select All**
2. Transform glyphs **Element → Transformations → Transform**

   This opens the transform dialog

   1. Set origin to glyph origin
   2. Choose Scale and set the vertical value as you want
   3. Ok

Review, rename and export.

This by nature avoids doing anything for spacing, ligatures, or kerning so they would stay the same. If you were to scale horizontally it would cause some issues. But you can just make the reference size smaller to compensate, in which case its the same thing.

Comment: Thanks!  Combined with the "change weight", this produced a great Bold variant really easily.